# How to align in parallel a Brep object using one of its face to XY, XZ, or YZ plane?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I tried a few possibilities but I could not get it right. On `SelectionChanged`, I create a `plane` from a selected face.  This is good, I can get the `plane` correctly.

```
                    var item = e.AddedItems[0];
                    if (item is Model.SelectedFace)
                    {
                        var faceItem = ((Model.SelectedFace)item);
                        var ent = faceItem.Item;
                          if (ent is Brep)
                          {
                            var sol = (Brep)ent;
                            if (faceItem.ShellIndex == 0)
                            {
                                var mesh = sol.Faces[faceItem.Index].ConvertToMesh();
                                var plane = new Plane(mesh.Vertices[0], mesh.Vertices[1], mesh.Vertices[2]);
                            }
                          }
                    }
```

The`xyTheta, xzTheta, and yzTheta` between the selected face's `plane` and `Plane.XY, Plane.XZ, & Plane.YZ` are correctly calculated. For the purpose of this question, I only show `xyTheta` as below (I already tried using this with `Transformation Matrix` but it did not work well either. Thus its purpose is just for me to check if the angle between the two planes is correct.

```
   var x0 = plane.Equation.X; var y0 = plane.Equation.Y; var z0 = plane.Equation.Z;
   var x1 = Plane.XY.Equation.X; var y1 = Plane.XY.Equation.Y; var z1 = Plane.XY.Equation.Z;

   xyTheta = Math.Acos(Math.Abs(x0 * x1 + y0 * y1 + z0 * z1)
                  / (Math.Sqrt(x0 * x0 + y0 * y0 + z0 * z0)
                  * Math.Sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 + z1 * z1)));
```

My transformation `transXY` can only do the `Translation` correctly but not the `Rotation`. For example, after transformated, my object still has 10 degree difference between `plane` and `Plane.XY`, although it gets moved.

```
       transXY = new Transformation();
       transXY.Rotation(plane, Plane.XY);
       // transXZ = new Align3D(plane, Plane.XZ);

        foreach (Entity ent in theModel.Entities)
        {
            ent.TransformBy(transXY);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plane.AxisX,Y,Z seem to work for the transformation matrix.  **Your BREP has to be transformed back to the origin for this to work, hence the transforming it by the inverse of the previous to move it back to origin.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using devDept.Eyeshot;
using devDept.Eyeshot.Entities;
using devDept.Geometry;

namespace EyeshotTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            makeSquare();
        }
        Solid3D square, square2;
        Transformation trans2 = new Transformation(1);
        int i = 0;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mesh faceMesh = square2.Faces[i].ConvertToMesh();
            var plane = new Plane(faceMesh.Vertices[0], faceMesh.Vertices[1], faceMesh.Vertices[2]);

            Point3D origin = plane.Origin;
            Vector3D xVec = plane.AxisX;
            Vector3D yVec = plane.AxisY;
            Vector3D zVec = plane.AxisZ;

            trans2.Invert();

            square.TransformBy(trans2);

            trans2 = new Transformation(origin, xVec, yVec, zVec);

            square.TransformBy(trans2);

            viewportLayout1.Entities.Regen();
            viewportLayout1.Invalidate();

            i++;
            if(i == 4) { i = 0; }
        }

        private void makeSquare()
        {
            square = Solid3D.CreateBox(5, 5, 5, 0.01);
            square2 = Solid3D.CreateBox(5, 5, 5, 0.01);

            viewportLayout1.Entities.Add(square, Color.Green);
            viewportLayout1.Entities.Add(square2, Color.FromArgb(75, Color.Blue));

            Transformation trans = new Transformation(new double[,]{
                {-0.17,0.67,0.72, 47.33 },
                {0.28,-0.67,0.69, 10.24 },
                {0.95,0.32,-0.07, 15.98 },
                {0,0,0,1 } });

            square2.TransformBy(trans);

            viewportLayout1.Invalidate();           
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Works now or not???

ent.TransformBy(transformation); This is wrong.

ent.TransformBy(transXY); This is right if enything else is ok.

Regards

Comment: thanks for the help. It was a typo but it was not the issue for the transformation